# Graph Editor Version

Tags: graph-editor

my new in blender, my graph editor looks very tall and not easy to use.
any one knows which setting I should do?

Thanks in advance:)

[image]

Comment: If you enter the "Home" key, the graph editor will center your selected graph in its window, giving you maximum visibility to the graph.

Comment: Hi Janice, i would recommend watching these: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/ they are free and really good for beginners.